# What restrictions are there on explicit equations?

Tags: functions, operator-theory, graphing-functions

So I've always been told that for a function to be considered explicit it can only have one specific output for each input or simply pass the vertical line test. While I can accept that on it's face I can't help but wonder about using $\pm$ to rewrite implicit equations like the function for a circle.

$1=x^2+y^2$

as this...

$y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$

To essentially make it into a explicit equation that returns two answers. I have a feeling that $\pm$ is just simply not an operator in the conventional sense but is short hand to avoid unnecessary writing. Does anyone have any hard facts in regards to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between an implicit function and an explicit function can best be understood by the english definitions of "implicit" and "explicit". I refer you to the English department for greater details there.

An implicit function is simply a function where the dependency is implied but not expressly stated. For example, $x-y-1=0$ could be such that $y$ is a function of $x$ implicitly. However, if I say $y=f(x)=x-1$, I am explicitly stating that $y$ is a function of $x$. There is not much more to know here. A function can be either explicitly stated or implicitly stated.

Note that for the case of $y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$, certainly $y$ is not a function of $x$.

Comment: I guess I wasn't incredibly clear with the intent of my question but am I safe to assume that using $\pm$ will basically nullify a functions ability to be considered explicit?

Comment: So in response to your most recent edit why is $y=f(x)=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$ not valid?

Comment: Yes basically the $\pm$ operator in $y=\pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$ means that $y$ is no function of $x$ as a function cannot be one to many, but if you were to initially declare that $y \geq 0$, then in $1=x^2+y^2$, $y$ could be considered an implicit function of $x$.

Comment: @rosscowar definitely say something if this is not clear enough. It is no problem. For something to be a function it must meet the definition of a function. If you have that then good, if not then don't be shy.

Comment: Well it turns out the answer I really needed was in the definition of the function which I found [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/FunctionDefn.aspx). It was never made clear that a `function` must only return a single value rendering $\pm$ an invalid operator inside a function.

Comment: Man that is excellent! Knowledge is a beautiful thing.

Comment: I agree! I've been building a graphing calculator and have been wondering about these things more and more all of the time. Would you be interested in moving this into chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10879/discussion-between-j-w-perry-and-rosscowar)